# Wi-Fi not touchable; froze my laptop

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

My laptop's hasn't been connecting to any wireless network. It's always disabled and I use a ethernet cable instead. However it did happen that I enabled the Wi-Fi; once I touched the turn-on button it ***froze*** my laptop. I can still turn it off, but it doesn't initialize anymore. My laptop boots like in 10s and then gets frozen in the booting screen.

However, I got into the Safe Mode automatically after restarting it several times. Safe Mode allows me to use cmd, so I wonder how could I *disable* the Wi-Fi to get Windows 10 running. Is there any `netsh` command to disable it even though I don't know my network device?

I did `$ netsh interface show interface`, but nothing's shown. It also says a auxiliar DLL `WLANCFG.DLL` can't be loaded. Should I use a pendrive to push such DLL to the shell location? `$ netsh mode offline`, still nothing.

So, according to @MarianD, there's nothing to do with cmd. Should I use another OS, then?

Comment: In the Safe Mode are not loaded drivers and DLLs for working with networks.

Comment: @MarianD Now I were able to load DLLs within Safe Mode. I did `netsh set mode offline`, but not sure if this disabled the Wi-Fi.

Comment: My Windows did now initialize, but only the cursor is there. I think I disabled something.

Comment: Try to boot in Safe Mode with Network.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to stop the Wi-Fi forever-loop. Cmd wasn't the solution, it's simply *Initialize in Safe Mode* (don't choose Safe Mode with Network, nor the Safe Mode with Command Prompt (which'll only show cmd)).

If you did go with `Initialize in Safe Mode with cmd` and can't exit it anyway, then press `Ctrl + Alt + Del` and exit with `Shift + Restart`.

In Safe Mode desktop you don't have network. Manage devices and disable the Wireless there and you can get back to normal desktop mode by going to boot screen back (there in Advanced Options).